# How do you know which dependencies must be added to a nuspec file when publishing a nuget?

Tags: c#, dependencies, nuget, nuspec

In my company we have many many repositories, and in the nuspec files, sometimes I see some dependencies added, sometimes not. For example, some projects have

```
<dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="13.0.3" />
```

But some others don't, while both projects use Newtonsoft.Json! I'm kinda afraid to add or remove stuff from here since I don't understand enough what dependencies have to be added and what dependencies don't.

I am not asking what dependencies my projects needs. I am asking when do we have to add a dependency to the nuspec, and when we don't need to add it.

Also, I need to be compatible with older versions of the framework, so I'm afraid I still have to maintain nuspec files and can't rely only on dotnet pack

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: How long is a piece of string? How can we tell what dependencies your code needs? You should try asking other devs in your company, especially if you are going to be removing stuff.

Comment: Today you just need to run `dotnet pack` and it will take care of dependencies.